# tls.connect on ipv6 on machine yields ENETUNREACH

Tags: node.js, ssl, ipv6

I am using node JS on an IPv6-only machine to connect securely to another server. However, when I use `tls.connect`, I consistently (and sadly) get `ENETUNREACH`. Here's a sample of the code I'm trying:

```
var connection = tls.connect(6443, 'irc.something.net', {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/some/path/to/certs/this/works/fine.pem'),
}, function() {
  console.log('OMG it worked?!');
});
```

This code works fine when I run it on a machine that supports both IPv4 AND IPv6, but when I run it on an IPv6-only machine, the `console.log` is never hit and I get the `ENETUNREACH` error instead.

Is there anything special that I need to do for IPv6?

Here's the error's stack trace, in case that helps:

```
Error: connect ENETUNREACH
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at connect (net.js:766:19)
    at net.js:845:9
    at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
```

Halp?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: Also, what platform are you running this on?

Comment: i'm using an older version - 0.6.13, and os is centos

Comment: Yikes that's *really* ancient. I believe your issue may be solved in recent node.js versions (perhaps since v0.12) as there was a similar issue [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7637) from some time ago. So you might try a newer node version first. I'd recommend starting with the latest stable (v5.2.0) that way we can know if there is currently a bug or not.

Comment: Seems to work fine in 0.10.x on CentOS 7. Time to get your environment up to date.